# How to Fade Captions in Supersized! Slider

Tags: javascript

Hi Guys: Would you please tell me why the following code does not animate (fade-in and out) the slide captions in Supersized! plugin? I am substituting the original code with the animated code as follows.

Original code:

```
if ($(vars.slide_caption).length)
{
   (api.getField('title'))?$(vars.slide_caption).html(api.getField('title')):$(vars.slide_caption).html('');
}
```

Changed it to:

```
    if ($(vars.slide_caption).length){
  (api.getField('title')) ? 
  $(vars.slide_caption).fadeOut("slow", function(){
    $(this).html(api.getField("title")).fadeIn("slow")
  }) :
  $(vars.slide_caption).fadeOut().html('');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, but it already works. It was my mistake. I was including *supersized.shutter.min.js* on the page, but the right file is *supersized.shutter.js*, wherein I made the change.